# Java - Use ThreadPoolExecutor of pool size 1 to queue and execute tasks 1 by 1

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Assume you have two processes `pA` and `pB` that are meant to execute different tasks.

Assume also, that `pA` is the one responsible for setting off the execution of `pB`, and that while `pB` is executing `pA` should still be able to handle its own tasks, including accepting requests to set off the execution of `pB`.

However, there should only be one `pB` active at any given time. Any extra requests received by `pA` for the execution of `pB` should be queued and handled once the last instance of `pB` has finished executing.

I suppose this is not such an unusual scenario of multitasking/concurrency, but I am unsure of how to implement it in a thread-safe and efficient way in java.

My initial idea was to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with maximum number of threads set to `1`. And implement each `pB` by a class that extends the `Runnable` interface and executes everything inside its `public void run()` method. From what I have understood from the documentation, this will lead in a single available thread from the pool, handling the tasks I create one by one, while all the others wait in a pre-implemented queue for a new available thread. All this, without blocking the execution of the current thread (`pA`).

Is this really the case? Is there anything else I should take into account or a simpler more standard way to implement this?

Practically testing all possible scenarios of such a configuration is not really easy, so thanks in advance.

Comment: what are "the threads I create one by one"? If you use ThreadPoolExecutor, you do not create threads yourself.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov you're right, what I mean by 'threads' is each instance of the class which represents process A (and implements Runnable) and which I pass to the execute method of the ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: that Runnable objects  usually are called tasks

Comment: Sounds about right. You can use the [newSingleThreadExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) method to get an executor matching what you want